# JavaFX FileChooser - close programmatically?

Tags: java, javafx, tdd, filechooser

JavaFX `FileChooser` subclasses as final from `Object`, and none of its methods looks promising.  It's just a bit annoying from a TDD point of view (end-to-end test).  Is the idea just to mock the whole business of choosing a file?

Swing `JFileChooser` was a proper `JComponent`: you could dig into it, mess around with it, subclass it, etc.  With `FileChooser` I don't even see how we could get a `Robot` or JavaFX framework to select things, press buttons, etc.  Seems a bit ... monolithic.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The javaFX Filechooser is a native FileChooser, how do you think, thinkering with it would work out? If you want more control over a FileChooser, use either JFileChooser, or the awt FileChooser.

Comment: Swing is being phased out.

Comment: Its still available, and will propably be for quite some time (just like awt). So why not using it? Appart from this, what is your actual question? If you dont formulate one properly, this post might get closed as it is unclear what you are asking right now.

Comment: The question is formulated perfectly OK.  If you don't understand it or want to vote it down for another reason, feel free.

Comment: downvote because question is not clear.

Comment: The JavaFX filechooser is a hook into the native filechooser, as stated both in the documentation and in a previous comment. So clearly it cannot be a JavaFX node or window. It is not at all clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @James_D it's a hook that returns a value. Or alternatively saves a file to a location.  Why there should be no way of closing the thing programmatically, i.e. without a human being pressing a button, for testing or other purposes is not clear and is a legitimate question.  Why this should be considered an unreasonable thing to ask is unfathomable, as is your insistence that you don't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: sry, reverted my downvote because I didn't take the title into account.

Comment: The FileChooser opens a modal dialog and blocks until the user makes her choice. How would you want to close it? From another thread? How would you have closed the JFileChooser which behaves the same? For Testing purpose I would suggest to mock it.

Comment: Tx... yes, with a JFileChooser you can dig into it and get hold of the Window object and then close that... from the EDT IIRC... anyway, yes, it looks like I'll have to mock this... which means making another method public, such as "getFileFromFileChooser()"... Oh well...